# What's a simple way to return the first regex match in a string with modern C++?

Tags: regex, string, c++11, idioms

What is a simple way to return the first part of a string that matches a regex in C++11?

Example: For the string `"The great brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."` and the regexp `/g[a-z]+/` the returned match would be `"great"`

Comment: Yes, that is a regex. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It looks like I figured out what OP was asking for; although, frankly, it may very well be a dupe.

Comment: @Qix: I think Someprogrammerdude's comment was somewhat more helpful than yours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

// ... include first_match() somewhere...

int main()
{
    std::string subject("The great brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
    std::string result;
    std::regex re("g[a-z]+");
    std::smatch match;
    if (std::regex_search(subject, match, re)) { std::cout << match.str(0); }
    else { std::cout << "(No matches)"; }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

If you'd like that as a function, I'd allow myself to use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). It's part of C++17, not C++11, but it's already available in C++14 as `std::experimental::optional`, and for C++11 you can use Boost's [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)) instead. Having it available, you would write something like this:

```
std::optional<std::string> first_match(
    const std::string&  str, 
    const std::regex&   expression)
{
    std::smatch match;
    return std::regex_search(str, match, expression) ?
        std::optional<std::string>(match.str(0)) : std::nullopt;
}
```

which you can use as follows:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

int main()
{
    std::cout <<
        first_match(
            "The great brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.", "g[a-z]+"
        ).value_or("(no matches)") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```